# Can you identify this European uniform or awards?

Tags: europe, 19th-century

[image: man in dark uniform with a white fringed sash and a saber]This is my great great grandfather.  I am having trouble identifying the uniform. It should be from around 1860-1890 ish. It would be from a German speaking country. The story that was passed down was that he was part of a royal guard before he set sail for the US. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you send an enlarged and better-focused  view of the medals & insignia, that is, of the breast, neck, and shoulder part of the image?